# Checkbox does not work well after resetting

Tags: reactjs

I have a checkbox component, it works well when checking and unchecking. But if I reset, then select the checkbox again, it does not respond the click and only works after a few clicks. Sometimes it throws the error message "TypeError: this.setState is not a function". What is the problem here? Thanks.
App.js

```
const campusData = [
  { id: 1, value:'A',name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, value:'B',name: 'B' },
  { id: 3, value:'C',name: 'C' }

]
class App extends Component{
 state={checkedCampusItems:[]};
onReset=()=>{
this.setState({checkedCampusItems:[]});

handleCampusChkChange=(id,name,value, checked)=> {

    const checkedCampusItems = this.state.checkedCampusItems;
    let index;

    // check if the check box is checked or unchecked
    if (checked) {
      // add the numerical value of the checkbox to checkedItems array

      checkedCampusItems.push(value);
    } else {

      index = checkedCampusItems.indexOf(value);
      checkedCampusItems.splice(index, 1);
    }

    // update the state with the new array of options
    this.setState({checkedCampusItems: checkedCampusItems });

    console.log("checkedCampusItems array",checkedCampusItems);

  }



render(){
    return(<div><input type="reset" value="Reset Search" onClick={this.onReset}></input>
            {campusData.map(item =>
           <CampusChk id="campus" key={item.id} {...item} onChange={this.handleCampusChkChange} />
          )}
</div>
)

}
}
export default App;
```

campusChk.js

```
    import React from 'react';


const CampusChk = ({ id, name,value, onChange }) => {
    return(
      <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={(event) => onChange(id,name,value, event.target.checked) }
    />
    <label>{name}</label>
    </div>

  );
}


export default CampusChk;
```

Comment: Inside `onReset` you're setting a new variable named `checkedCampusItems` rather than updating `App`'s state

Comment: Your edit is still incorrect. `this.setState({checkedCampusItems=[]});` is not valid. You're setting an object key, you cant assign it with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your reset function to update the state:

```js
onReset=()=>{
  this.setState({ checkedCampusItems: []})
}
```

You're also mutating state. This may not be causing the problem, but you should change your temporary array to this in your change handler:

```js
const checkedCampusItems = [...this.state.checkedCampusItems];
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to this.setState({checkedCampusItems:[]}) and it still does not work well. I guess something is wrong with the reset event.

Comment: After making changes to this.setState({checkedCampusItems:[]}) in onReset() function, no more "TypeError: this.setState is not a function" but the console.log shows the checkedCampusItems array does not record all the selected value after resetting.

Comment: You are not providing a value to your checkbox either? Where does `campusData` come from that you're mapping over?

Comment: When you don't provide a value or in the case of a checkbox a `checked` value, it will be an uncontrolled input, and resetting the state will cause the input and what your state says the input should be to become out of sync.

Comment: My problem right now is after clicking Reset button, and then select values in checkbox list, the state of the checkboxlist does not get updated correctly. It only gets updated after a few clicks. Any idea?